# Show info with controller in Ionic with AngularJS. ¿When the controller is called?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am beginner on Ionic Framework, and I find a problem that I dont be able find solution. Well, it's is a extract for my code:

I have this code in view.html

```
  <ion-item class="item-remove-animate item-avatar item-icon-right" ng-repeat="nota in notas" >
      <h1>{{nota.titulo}}</h1>
      <h2>{{nota.texto}}</h2>
    </ion-item>
```

This is my controler:

```
.controller('ChatsCtrl', function($scope, Chats, $cordovaSQLite) {
  $scope.notas= Chats.getNotas();
})
```

And in services.js the function getNotas() is something like this:

```
.factory('Chats', function( $cordovaSQLite) {

  return {

    getNotas: function() {
    ...
  }
 }
}
```

Well, when I enter on the app screen that show the info from DB, it work well, but I don't understand why the last record don't show., But nevertheless, when I recharge the page F5 (in the browser) the record appear. I understand that the controller is called when the view is called to render, but, if I set a new note in other view, why when I try see this last record in other view this dont show?
I think that this problem should be a foolish, but I don't understand why this happens.
The app it's a simple project that set and get notes from SQLite database, I thought that it would be easier.
Thanks you so much.

```
//Controlador DasControl
.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaSQLite) {

    $scope.insert = function(titulo, texto) {
      if (window.cordova) {
        db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: "my.db" }); //device
      }else{
        db = window.openDatabase("my.db", '1', 'my', 1024 * 1024 * 100); // browser
      }
        var query = "INSERT INTO people (title, text) VALUES (?,?)";
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, [titulo, texto]).then(function(res) {
            console.log("INSERT ID -> " + res.insertId);
        }, function (err) {
            console.error(err);
        });                      
    }



})

//Controlador para la vista de notas
.controller('ChatsCtrl', function($scope, Chats, $cordovaSQLite) {
  $scope.notas= Chats.getNotas();
})
```

When I call the function insert the work fine, but when I call the second controler only work when I reload the page.

```
.factory('Chats', function( $cordovaSQLite) {

  return {

    getNotas: function() {

      console.log("peticion notas");

      //Consulta en la base de datos
      if (window.cordova) {
        db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: "my.db" }); //device
      }else{
        db = window.openDatabase("my.db", '1', 'my', 1024 * 1024 * 100); // browser
      }
          //Creamos un vector donde vamos a introducir las notas.
          var notas = [];
          var salida = null;
          var query = "SELECT * FROM people";
          var res = $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query).then(function(res) {
              var len = res.rows.length;
              if(len>0) {
              for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                notas.push({
                  titulo: res.rows.item(i).title,
                  texto: res.rows.item(i).text
                });
                console.log("SELECTED -> " + res.rows.item(i).title + " " + res.rows.item(i).text);
              }
            }
              if(res.rows.length > 0) {
                 console.log("SELECTED -> " + res.rows.item(0).title + " " + res.rows.item(0).text);
              } else {
                  console.log("No results found");
              }
          }, function (err) {
              console.error(err);
          });
          return notas;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update the $scope.notas, every time you add new note, you can use events.

So, when, I new note is added, send event, in, the add note controller :

```
$rootScope.$broadCast('notaAdded', newNotaObject);
```

And, then, listen & add new node in the ChatsCtrl :

```
$rootScope.$on('notaAdded', function(event, newNota){
    $scope.notas.push(newNota);
})
```

Comment: I understand you, but I dont know why I need reload the page (F5) to see the data in the list...